# How to access variable defined browse button class outside class scope

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have called a class of browse button(to select file location) from main function. This class has browse function to capture file-path variable that stores the path. Now I just want to use this file path defined in class function outside this class like print this variable outside the class scope

I have already tried giving loc as global, other access methods but not of them worked I guess its due to arguments being passed to class.

```py
'''Using Tkinter module'''

class Browse(tk.Frame,object):
    # here __init__ ,_create_widgets,_display_widgets are defined then I have,

    def browse(self):
        """ Browses a .xlsx file or all files and then puts it on the entry.
        """

        self.filepath.set(fd.askopenfilename(initialdir=self._initaldir,
                                                 filetypes=self._filetypes))
        print(self.filepath.get()), self      #Path of ATP choosen by user
        loc = self.filepath.get()            #want to excess this out of class
```

I want to print 'loc' value (able to print inside) outside the the class scope
how can I access the same. I guess the problem is being caused due to arguments my class has, though not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, `loc` is a local variable in the `browse` function, and it will cease to exist when the `browse` function returns.  If you write it as:

```
        self.loc = self.filepath.get()
```

Then if you have a `Browse` object called `b`, you can just write `b.loc` to access it.

If you want to access the variable even if there is no `Browse` object to hand, you will need a class variable.  Set with:

```
        Browse.loc = self.filepath.get()
```

and access with `Browse.loc`.  The problem with class variables is the same as with all global variables though - what if you have two `Browse` objects? and what if you try to access the class variable from multiple threads?

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, you can accept it by clicking the grey tick mark just under the number and up/down arrows.  You can change which answer you have accepted on a question at any time, but you may want to delay accepting one answer in order to encourage other (possibly better) answers.  (People are less likely to answer a question which already has an accepted answer.)